# How to use skin file in my aspx page

Tags: dotnetnuke-7

I am preety new for DotNetNuke. I want to create a sample skin and that I can use for my aspx page. I have downloaded and installed Starter Kit. Please help me how can I integrate my skin file to the aspx page. All I know is we have to do some steps to create skin in dnn7 website. However I dont have any idea furthermore.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

After you have created your skin files(s) you need to upload them to a named subdirectory in /portals/_default/skins.  The you can apply the skin to pages in your site using Page Settings.

If you are looking for some helpful tutorials, you will find some helpful videos at dnnsoftware.com, dnnhero.com and dnncreative.com.